# African Violet Flower Issues

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, flowers, african-violets

I was wondering if anyone knows why my African Violet flowers are dying? I was thinking it is too much sun but not sure if anyone has had this issue and resolved it.
[image]

Comment: Good question; if could include an overall illustration, overall plant width, current watering amount & frequency, current nutrient amount & frequency, size of container, the soil, average daytime temperature, average night time temperature, number of hours direct sunlight & number of hours of diffused light per day, and if some coarse gravel in the bottom and a hole in the bottom for good aereation & drainage, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [African violets](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/african-violets/growing-guide) do not like too much direct sunlight, but based on the photo that is not the problem.

Brown spots on the leaves indicates you have spilled waters drops on the leaves, and they certainly do not like this.

Yellow leaves indicates that they have been soaking. Ideally, only supply water
in the bottom of the pot/container, not on the top of the soil, and always remember to empty the container for water not absorbed by the soil 10 minutes after watering.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostically: Since your foliage isn’t scorched, you can rule out “too much sun” as the cause of your flower die-off, at least.

I hope others can give you more specific help! :)